# Socket.io takes a long time before triggering the disconnect event

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, socket.io

I'm doing an HTML5 Game using node.js and socket.io

I decided to host it on [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/).

Heroku isn't allowing the use of WebSockets, so I have to setup xhr-polling instead. ([Socket-io on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku))

```
io.configure( function() {
    io.set( "transports", ["xhr-polling"] );
    io.set( "polling duration", 10 );
} );
```

Before, I was using web-sockets only

```
io.set( "transports", ["websocket"] );
```

Now, when a client disconnect (close his window or refresh his page) the event "disconnect" isn't trigger immediatly on the server (it looks like it's waiting for the client heartbeat to time out).

```
client.on( "disconnect", onClientDisconnect );
```

If the client reloads, I get multiple connection events **before** disconnect is fired.
My problem is here.

Do you have any ideas, why xhr-polling doesn't fire the disconnect event ?
Is this a bad configuration of socket.io ?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to know if a client using xhr-polling disconnects until they don't respond to the heartbeat, since it doesn't use a persistent connection.

Answer (score 1):

It says [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec#2-heartbeat) that you can configure the heartbeat. To properly configure it, you must adjust the heartbeat both on the server and the client side (which is given [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO)).

Try lowering the heartbeat. It may solve your problem.
On other note, appfog seems to support websockets.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to put a lower heartbeat to reduce my problem. Appfog seems cool too and would have solved my problem but I want to use Heroku for personnal reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just configure session auth and you can always know what client has connected. E.g.

```
io.set('authorization', function(handshakeData, ack) {
    var cookies = require(...);
    var signedCookies = parseCookies(cookies, secret);
    sessionStore.get(signedCookies['connect.sid'], function(err, sessionData) {
        handshakeData.session = sessionData || {};
        handshakeData.sid = signedCookies['connect.sid'] || null;
        ack(err, err ? false : true);
    });
});
```