# Socket.io client disconnect event emitted after a long time (>1min). Client disconnect detection

Tags: android, ios, socket.io

Related questions:

- [Socket.io takes a long time before triggering the disconnect event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168842/socket-io-takes-a-long-time-before-triggering-the-disconnect-event)
- [Socket.io delay in firing the "disconnect" event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192747/socket-io-delay-in-firing-the-disconnect-event)
- https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/635

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the client's problem, but an improper server configuration. Socket.io has a ping / pong mechanism for detecting disconnects.

An socket.io server has those options:

> pingTimeout (Number): how many ms without a pong packet to consider the connection closed (60000)
>
> pingInterval (Number): how many ms before sending a new ping packet (25000).
>
> Those two parameters will impact the delay before a client knows the server is not available anymore. For example, if the underlying TCP connection is not closed properly due to a network issue, a client may have to wait up to pingTimeout + pingInterval ms before getting a disconnect event.
>
> via https://socket.io/docs/server-api/